# Grant access to only one directory with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to only provide public access to a single directory (/dist). I have an .htaccess file with the following:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all

<Directory /dist>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I'm trying to first deny access to all, then overwirte that directive with a allow rule for the /dist directory. However, when I try to access any file through the browser, I get the following:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at you@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Directory` directive isn't allowed in .htaccess

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Anubhava said, Directory dirctive is not allowed in htaccess contex ,this directive is available for use only in Directory context. You can use a RewriteRule to deny access to all except /dist directory :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule !dist - [F]
```

This will forbid all incomming requests except a request for /dist.